# Why is every element of my array wrapped in array([]) when creating an array from a pandas dataframe with a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

So I was given the assignment to create 5 arrays(numerical) using the data from a column of a given database. I used pandas to read my data and tried to take the numbers from a column using a for loop. Here is what I did:

```
import pandas

#Problem 1
print()
loans = pandas.read_csv("/Users/LM/Downloads/loans_full_schema.csv")
df = pandas.DataFrame(loans)
a = []
for i in df[['total_credit_lines']].values:
    a.append(i)


print('total credit lines', a)
```

Here's what I got when I ran it:

```
total credit lines [array([28]), array([30]), array([31]), array([4]), array([22]), array([32]), array([12]), array([30]), array([35]), array([9]), array([22]), array([26]), array([32]), array([65]), array([22]), array([21]), array([21]), array([12]), array([18]), array([11]), array([13]), array([19]), array([64]), array([10]), array([26]), array([20]), array([17]), array([9]), array([13]), array([26]), array([36]), array([37]), array([31]), array([27]), array([21]), array([13]), array([9]), array([21]), array([12]), array([6]), array([12]), array([24]), array([29]), array([11]), array([15]), array([30]), array([17]), array([23]), array([9]), array([39]), array([21]), array([37]), array([11]), array([27]), array([21]), array([6]), array([39]), array([28]), array([15]), array([26]), array([27]), array([22]), array([6]), array([28]), array([22]), array([37]), array([27]), array([16]), array([15]), array([6]), array([13]), array([32]), array([5]), array([11]), array([23]), array([15]), array([11]), array([23]), array([32]), array([31]), array([11]), array([21]), array([24]), array([30]), array([32]), array([40]), array([44]), array([35]), array([21]), array([21]), array([23]), array([11]), array([40]), array([39]), array([22]), array([15]), array([9]), array([18]), array([19]), array([31]), array([11]), array([11]), array([41]), array([29]), array([41]), array([11]), array([27]), array([16]), array([15]), array([22]), array([15]), array([30]), array([16]), array([18]), array([14]), array([12]), array([25]), array([23]), array([20]), array([55]), array([34]),
```

So how do I remove the array([]) from around the values? What could be the problem?

Comment: Because, have you seen what `i` is on each iteration? Why are you doing this anyway? There's no need to loop here I think you just want `df['total_credit_lines'].tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use loops and iteration here. Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/LM/Downloads/loans_full_schema.csv")
a = df['total_credit_lines'].tolist()
print('total credit lines', a)
```